# mysql get parent and child records in a single query

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am using the below code to get the parent record and their associated records using fld_tmp filed.fld_tmp=0 means parent record if child records having the fld_tmp id is 98795. The below query return error table q does not exist.

```
select fld_id,fld_date,fld_pay_total,fld_user_id 
from tbl_paymet q where fld_id=98795 and fld_tmp=0
union 
select t1.fld_id,t1.fld_date,t1.fld_pay_total,t1.fld_user_id 
from tbl_paymet t1 left join  q on t1.fld_tmp=q.fld_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, I don't think you need the `UNION`, i don't think you need the `fld_tmp=0` either since you know the id of the record you're looking for but it doesn't hurt to have it in there.

```
select fld_id,fld_date,fld_pay_total,fld_user_id 
from tbl_paymet q 
where (fld_id=98795 and fld_tmp=0)
   or (fld_tmp=98795)
order by fld_tmp asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Each table referenced in a MySQL `LEFT JOIN` needs to be spelled out in full, it can't use previously defined aliases. You can, however, assign a new alias for the join itself.